# Echo PHP array from loop

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to echo an array from loop, but it doesn't seemed to be work.

Code, to put values in array:

```
      public function get_language() {

        global $db;

        $language = $this->get_visit_loc();
        $rows = array();
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM languages WHERE lang_id = '{$language}'") or die(mysql_error());
        if($db->num_rows($query) > 0) {
            while($row = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
        } else {
            $rows['error'] = 'We have some serious Error!';
        }
        return $rows;
    }
```

If I call the function and try to echo the array, it returns nothing.

```
   $lan = $lang->get_language();

   echo $lan['lang_id']; //returns nothing.

   echo $lan['error']; //Returns an error.
```

print_r result:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [lang_id] => EE ) )
```

Comment: `echo $lan[0]['lang_id']` works?

Comment: `$rows[] = $row;` so to access each row you need to do `$lan[0]['lang_id']`

Comment: What you need is `echo $lan[0]['lang_id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you got a two dimensional array for a single language. As you have a single language, so use the code as below:

```
if($db->num_rows($query) > 0) {
            while($row = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
                return $row;
            }
        } else {
            $rows['error'] = 'We have some serious Error!';
        }
```

As you are getting single result (assuming you have a single record for each language ID, as it is always like that :) ), then there is no need to do the following

```
$rows[] = $row;
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to iterate through the loop to get the internal rows/arrays. The `error` key would only exist in the first array.

```
if(!empty($lan['error']))
    echo $lan['error'];
else{
    foreach($lan as $l){
        echo $l['lang_id'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lang_id is in an array that is nested in the first item of another array so it should be

```
echo $lan[0]['lang_id']
```